# Marquee inside css through onlick button action on javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new in javascript and having a hard time finishing my school work.
This is my current code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <style>
 div {
     background-color: white;
     width: 200px;
     border: 25px solid blue;
     padding: 25px;
     margin: 25px;
     position: relative;
     left: 35%;
 }
 h2 {
    text-align: center;
     }
 </style>
 <body>
 <br><br>
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Sunday</button><br>
 <button onclick="myFunction2()">Monday</button><br>
 <button onclick="myFunction3()">Tuesday</button><br>
 <button onclick="myFunction4()">Wednesday</button><br>
 <button onclick="myFunction5()">Thursday</button><br>
 <button onclick="myFunction6()">Friday</button><br>
 <button onclick="myFunction7()">Saturday</button><br>
 <p id="demo"></p>

 <script>
 function myFunction() {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="<div><h2>Sunday</h2></div>";
 }
 function myFunction2() {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<div><h2>Monday</h2></div>";
 }
 function myFunction3() {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<div><h2>Tuesday</h2>     </div>";
 }
 function myFunction4() {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<div><h2>Wednesday</h2>     </div>";
 }
 function myFunction5() {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<div><h2>Thursday</h2></div>";
 }
 function myFunction6() {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<div><h2>Friday</h2>     </div>";
 }
 function myFunction7() {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<div><h2>Saturday</h2>     </div>";
 }
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

The blue rectangular-like shape has to go down starting from the top of the page right after clicking any button, and after it reach the botttom like just touching it, the color of the box needs to be inverted. what I know is that it is marquee but I do not know the proper code for it. I know this is a lot, that's why I am asking for help. any comments are appreciated :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want the box to slide down just after the first button click, then this code will do it for you:

```js
 function myFunction() {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="<div><h2>Sunday</h2></div>";
     document.getElementById("demo").style.marginTop = "10%";
     document.querySelector("div").style.borderColor = "#40A824";
 }
 function myFunction2() {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<div><h2>Monday</h2></div>";
     document.getElementById("demo").style.marginTop = "10%";
     document.querySelector("div").style.borderColor = "#003399";
 }
 function myFunction3() {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<div><h2>Tuesday</h2>     </div>";
     document.getElementById("demo").style.marginTop = "10%";
     document.querySelector("div").style.borderColor = "#9233DF";
 }
 function myFunction4() {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<div><h2>Wednesday</h2>     </div>";
     document.getElementById("demo").style.marginTop = "10%";
     document.querySelector("div").style.borderColor = "#CA4B98";
 }
 function myFunction5() {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<div><h2>Thursday</h2></div>";
     document.getElementById("demo").style.marginTop = "10%";
     document.querySelector("div").style.borderColor = "#5DA233";
 }
 function myFunction6() {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<div><h2>Friday</h2>     </div>";
     document.getElementById("demo").style.marginTop = "10%";
     document.querySelector("div").style.borderColor = "#5B1C5A";
 }
 function myFunction7() {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<div><h2>Saturday</h2>     </div>";
     document.getElementById("demo").style.marginTop = "10%";
     document.querySelector("div").style.borderColor = "#F4292A";
 }
```

```css
 div {
     background-color: white;
     width: 200px;
     border: 25px solid blue;
     padding: 25px;
     margin: 25px;
     position: relative;
     left: 35%;
 }
 h2 {
    text-align: center;
 }

 #demo {
     position: absolute;
     margin-top: -387px;
     transition: .5s;
 }
```

```html
 <br><br>
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Sunday</button><br>
 <button onclick="myFunction2()">Monday</button><br>
 <button onclick="myFunction3()">Tuesday</button><br>
 <button onclick="myFunction4()">Wednesday</button><br>
 <button onclick="myFunction5()">Thursday</button><br>
 <button onclick="myFunction6()">Friday</button><br>
 <button onclick="myFunction7()">Saturday</button><br>
 <p id="demo"></p>
```

Although this works in a fullscreen browser, it is not a reliable solution for different sized screens. Running the code snippet will give an undesired result, so you better copy the code and paste it into an HTML page.